# Number Theory: Find possible $n$ values that $n(n+1)(5n+2)$ is divisible by $2017^{2018}$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Assume $m= 2017^{2018}.$ How can I find possible value(s) of $n$ that $n < m$ and $n(n+1)(5n+2)$ is divisible by $m$.

Any hints?

Comment: Well, 2017 is prime.  And $n$ and $n+1$ are co prime.  And $n$ only have 2 as a common factor with n if n is even or with n+1 if n is odd So either $2017^{2018}$ divides $n$ completely, or it divides $n+1$ completely  or it divide $5n+2$ completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2017$ is prime.  $\gcd(n,n+1) = 1$, $\gcd(5n+2,n) = \gcd(2,n) = \{1,2\}$, $\gcd(5n+2, n+1) = \gcd(-3, n+1) = \{3,1\}$.  So if $2017^{2018}|n(n+1)(5n+2)$ then either

$2017^{2018}|n$ and $n = k*m$.

or $2017^{2018}|n+1$ and $n= k*m - 1$.

or $2017^{2018}|5n + 2$ and $n = \frac{km- 2}5$.  This requires $km \equiv 2 \mod 5$  As $2017 \equiv 2 \mod 5$ and $2^4 \equiv 1 \mod 5$, $2017^{2018} \equiv 2^2 \equiv 4 \mod 5$ so we need $4k \equiv 2 \mod 5$ so $k \equiv 3 \mod 5$.  $n = \frac{(5j+3)m - 2}5$

..... But (dopeslap!)  $n < m$ (didn't see that at first)

So $n = m -1$ or  $n = \frac {3m - 2}5$

Oh, or $n = 0$... or $n - 1$ or any of the *negative* multiples above.  I assume that $n$ is natural number....